# Flatpickr Date Range Session Storage in ISO format with AlpineJS Persist

Tags: date-formatting, alpine.js, session-storage, persist, flatpickr

I am using AplineJS Persist to store the date range of Flatpickr to session storage. This is my Flatpickr code:

```
            <div x-data="{
                thePicker: null,
                init() {
                    this.thePicker = flatpickr(this.$refs.picker, {
                        mode: 'range',
                        minDate: 'today',
                        inline: false,
                        dateFormat: 'M j',
                        showMonths: 2,
                        defaultDate: this.dateRange,
                        onChange: (selectedDates) => {this.dateRange = [...selectedDates];}
                    });
                },
            }"
            >
                <div class="flex items-center flex-1 gap-2 overflow-hidden border border-gray-500 rounded-lg">
                    <input type="text"
                        x-ref="picker"
                        placeholder="Add dates"
                        class="p-0 py-4 placeholder-gray-600 border-0 bg-none focus:ring-0"
                    >
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here is my x-data to store it with persist:

```
dateRange: $persist([]).using(sessionStorage).as('_x_range'),
```

The problem I am having is that the date range is being stored in ISO format, like so:

```
["2024-02-19T07:00:00.000Z","2024-02-22T07:00:00.000Z"]
```

And I am really struggling to understand how either store it as `M j` or format it back to `M j` from ISO.

In this case, I would be totally fine with storing it, for example:

`Jan 1 to Jan 8, 2024`

But then when displaying the date on the front-end via x-text or x-html, remove the year:

`Jan 1 to Jan 8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not advisable to alter the stored format.

You can use *onChange* and *onReady* events to replace the displayed format:

```js
init() {

    const rewriteRange = (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
        const year0 = selectedDates[0]?.getFullYear();
        if (selectedDates[0]  &&  year0 === selectedDates[1]?.getFullYear())
            instance.element.value = dateStr.replaceAll (' ' + year0, '');
    };

    this.thePicker = flatpickr(this.$refs.picker, {
        mode: 'range',
        inline: false,
        dateFormat: 'M j Y',
        showMonths: 2,
        defaultDate: this.dateRange,

        onChange: (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
            this.dateRange = [...selectedDates];
            rewriteRange (selectedDates, dateStr, instance);
        },

        onReady: (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
            rewriteRange (selectedDates, dateStr, instance);
        }
    });
}
```

This way the year is only displayed when the interval straddles two years (note the *dateformat*).

To display the range somewhere else in your own format, you can manupulate the dates e.g. using [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString):

```html
<div x-data="{

   .....

   init() {

      .....

   },

   displayRange() {
       return new Date(this.dateRange[0]).toLocaleDateString('en-us',{day: 'numeric', month: 'short'}) +
              ' to ' +
              new Date(this.dateRange[1]).toLocaleDateString('en-us',{day: 'numeric', month: 'short'}) +
              ', ' +  new Date(this.dateRange[0]).getFullYear()
   }
}">

   <!-- ..... -->

   <div x-text="displayRange"
        x-show="dateRange[0]  &&  dateRange[1]"
   > </div> 

</div>
```

Here *displayRange()* is a simplified example of how to compose your format

Comment: Thank you, this is excellent information. The problem I have is that I need to display the 'displayRange' outside of x-data.

So I was able to create a function for `displayRange()` and this worked quite well.